# rangeOfString returning not nil every time

Tags: xcode, string, swift, parsing

Whenever there is an error, which is stored in the variable `errorString`, I want to check if the error has the String, `"missing username"`. And if the `errorString` indeed has the String `"missing username"`, set `errorString` as `"missing email address"`. However, even if the `errorString` does not have `"missing username"`, `errorString` is set as `"missing email address"`. For example, even if the `errorString = 2015-09-08 11:44:39.937 ParseStarterProject-Swift[15182:93559] [Error]: invalid email address (Code: 125, Version: 1.8.2)`, it still sets `errorString` as `"missing email address"`. The part of the code where the problem lies is here:

```
if (errorString?.rangeOfString("missing username") != nil) {
    errorString = "missing email address"
}
```

And the rest of the relevant code is here:

```
@IBAction func signUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    let user = PFUser()
    user["firstName"] = firstName.text
    user["lastName"] = lastName.text
    user.email = emailAddress.text
    user.password = password.text
    user.username = emailAddress.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            var errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
            errorString = String(errorString!)
            print(errorString)

            if (errorString?.rangeOfString("missing username") != nil) {
                errorString = "missing email address"
            }

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\(errorString!)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                println("Handle Ok logic here")
            }))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at rangeOfString of *String* and *NSString*. The first returns *Range?*. The second returns *NSRange*. Your variable is inferred as *NSString*, so the test returns *NSRange*, not an optional Range and will never be nil. Change the variable type to String to get the desired behavior.

This should also work:

```
if (errorString!.rangeOfString("missing username").toRange() != nil) {
    errorString = "missing email address"
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response! It worked perfectly! THANK YOU!!! Also, I have some questions regarding your answer. Would it be possible for me to ask you in private chat? Moderators suggested additional questions should not be asked in the comment section.

Comment: If you have follow up questions, let me know. I don't know how to initiate private chat, though...

Comment: I think this is a random room that we can talk in. Thank you so much for being willing to answer my questions!

Comment: Here is the chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87935/room-for-blender-warrior-and-tom